# Why doesn't dev-server auto-create index for this query?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

This is how my entity class looks:

```
@Entity
@Unindexed
public class User {
    ...
    @Indexed
    private int betsCount = 0;
```

This is how I build/run the query:

```
objectify.query(User.class).filter("betsCount >", MIN_BETS).iterator()
```

The index is not being added to datastore-indexes-auto.xml, therefore I can not see it in the dev-console, and naturally the queries (when run on live servers) return nothing.

I know I could add the index (request it to be created) manually but so far automatic creating of indexes seemed to work perfectly for me. So I am wondering what am I missing here.

UPDATE: I did not realize I have to reinsert data when adding @Indexed annotation to existing property.

Comment: This is a single property index.  You do not need to specify a custom index for it, and it will not display in the indexes page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you're trying to run requires only a single property index.  You do not need to specify a custom index for it, and it will not display in the indexes page.

I suspect your issue is related to your use of @Unindexed, something else with the model definition, or possibly the data and criteria you're using.  Check the Objectify docs on [indexed / unindexed](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#@Indexed_and_@Unindexed) for a detailed description of indexes.  I would also verify that the data actually matches the criteria you're specifying.

Comment: I think I just might need to re-insert the entities because I added the Indexed annotation to that property only now. (The entities were inserted without Indexed on that property.)